# Issue with select option dropdown in IPAD pro

Tags: html, css, angular, ipad

I have an Select dropdown in my application which works as expected across all *Browsers* and *Operating Systems*, but when it comes to *IPAD pro* device I get extra empty rows at the bottom as illustrated in the image.

```
  <select name="monthfilter" id="monthfilter" class="form-control select-pointer" title="Month Filter" >
  <option [selected]="year == 0" value="0">Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let month of months" [value]="month.id">{{month.itemName}}
  </option>
  </select>
```

[image]

How do I avoid this strange behavior in my page ? I dont have any CSS property specific to Select element they are browser native.

Comment: Where is the code? screenshot is not enough*

Comment: Updated the question @Adam